# bulding aam-opencv in opencv 3.0 without legacy.hpp

Tags: opencv3.0

It seems that [delaunay.h](https://code.google.com/p/aam-opencv/source/browse/trunk/AAM/include/delaunay.h?r=13) in aam-opencv misses a library (legacy.hpp) in opencv3.0 which has been deprecated ([Planar Subdivisions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/legacy/doc/planar_subdivisions.html?highlight=planar%20subdivisions)). So, I get:

```
||=== Build: all in AAM (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\CodeBlocks\aam-opencv\include\delaunay.h|130|error: 'CvSubdiv2DEdge' has not been declared|
C:\CodeBlocks\aam-opencv\include\delaunay.h|135|error: 'CvSubdiv2D' does not name a type|
C:\CodeBlocks\aam-opencv\include\delaunay.h|137|error: 'CvSubdiv2D' does not name a type|
C:\CodeBlocks\aam-opencv\src\main.cpp||In member function 'void aamTrainer::loadModel(char*)':|
(...)
```

Is there any suggestions on how to fix it? Any new library/objects to substitute them?

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dclib/files/dlib/ seems to rule for facial landmarks, nowadays.

Comment: I am trying dlib for face tracking. I am still learning about it, but I found a nice guidelines on how to train the NN and which tool to use here: http://blog.dlib.net/2014/08/real-time-face-pose-estimation.html and https://gist.github.com/iandees/f773749c47d088705199

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV 3 has Subdiv2D class. Simply change CvSubdiv2D to Subdiv2D and make sure you include "imgproc.hpp". It has also got a getEdge method that will help you. Please, check opencv\samples\cpp\delaunay2.cpp . It has got the new methods working.